# How to do backward pagination in dynamoDB with LastEvaluatedKey?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

```
  param.FilterExpression = "#black_listed = :black_listed_val";
  param.Limit = 5
  param.ExpressionAttributeValues = {":black_listed_val": body.blacklisted};
  param.ExpressionAttributeNames = {"#black_listed": "black_listed"}
  param.ScanIndexForward = true
  param.ExclusiveStartKey = {"id": "11931258-b582-4d2d-98d9-aa8ae0fe2e43"}
```

I can do forward pagination with this code, but how could I go back?

Answer (score 3):

To page backward you need to set `ScanIndexForward` to `false` **AND** the `ExclusiveStartKey` to the key of the **first** item of the **second** page. As an example, say your first page is items 1, 2 & 3. The response from that will include a `LastEvaluatedKey` for 3. You can use that to go forward by passing that to the `ExclusiveStartKey`, resulting in 4, 5 & 6. Going backward you can't do that, because using that same key would result in just 2 & 1. Instead you need to use the key of 4 as your `ExclusiveStartKey`.

Comment: I tried the same query with both ScanIndexForward = true and ScanIndexForward = false. But the data it returns is the same and in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
param.ScanIndexForward = true
```

to

```
param.ScanIndexForward = false
```